# Forcing table-row to have height same as content

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am having the following structure of the web page.

Part 1: Header, fixed height

Part 2: Content, variable height

Part 3: Footer, fixed height

And I want the following to be true:

1) If the content is smaller than `screen_height - header_height - footer_height` : The footer should stick to bottom of page, giving the content all the screen space between header and footer.

2) If the content is larger than `screen_height - header_height - footer_height` : the page will scroll and the footer will be on the bottom of the page. (This case is already achievable, it's how all normal pages look)

To achieve first, I did the following

HTML:

```
<div class="page-content" style="display: table;height: 100%;width: 100%;">
    <div class="header-section" style="display: table-row;height: 10px;">
        Content here
    </div>
    <div id="content-section" style="display: table-row;height: auto;">
        Content here
    </div>
    <div id="footer-section" style="display: table-row;height: 230px;">
        Content here
    </div>
</div>
```

With this, the header row is spanning not 10px height but more. I want to confine the header row to just 10px height. Is this achievable with this table structure? And what about cross-browser compatibility?

Thanks.

Comment: set font-size and line-height less than 10px; for header row

Answer (score 0):

To reduce header height, add `line-height:10px` also.

You can add Javascript to apply height .

Please check the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/c8vq3Lbu/5/

Answer (score 0):

Tables try their very best to display everything in them. So since the text "content here" is higher than 10px, the top row will expand to show it all.

Possible solutions are

- Take the header out of the table and put it above. Ordinary blocks handle `height` in a more straightforward way.

  ```css
  html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <header class="header-section" style="height:10px; overflow:hidden">
    Content here
  </header>
  <div class="page-content" style="display:table; height:calc(100% - 10px); width:100%;">
    <div id="content-section" style="display:table-row; height:auto;">
      Content here
    </div>
    <div id="footer-section" style="display:table-row; height:230px;">
      Content here
    </div>
  </div>
  ```
- Put an extra div in the table cell in the header that you give the height. If a div in a table cell is 10px high, the cell won't have to expand, even if there is content overflowing.

  ```css
  html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="page-content" style="display:table; height:100%; width:100%;">
    <div class="header-section" style="display:table-row; height:10px; ">
      <div style="display:table-cell;">
        <div style="height:10px; overflow:hidden">
          Content here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content-section" style="display:table-row; height:auto;">
      Content here
    </div>
    <div id="footer-section" style="display:table-row; height:230px;">
      Content here
    </div>
  </div>
  ```
- Or, if the problem is that the content is actually 10px high, but you have a few pixels extra below it in the cell, it's probably that the content is inline and leaves room for a descender. In that case, the solution is to give the content `display:block` or `vertical-align:top` styles.

  ```css
  html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="page-content" style="display:table; height:100%; width:100%;">
    <div class="header-section" style="display:table-row; height:10px; ">
      <div style="display:table-cell;">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/10" alt="" style="display:block"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content-section" style="display:table-row; height:auto;">
      Content here
    </div>
    <div id="footer-section" style="display:table-row; height:230px;">
      Content here
    </div>
  </div>
  ```

As for cross-browser compatibility, it's usually best to emulate a full table (with nested divs being `table`, `table-row` and `table cell`) because older browsers may have problems with content being put directly inside a table row.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a table layout for achieving this.

Just do a `calc` for the `min-height` on your main content `div`. That's it. Use the viewport relative unit to get the height of the viewport (screen) and subtract the fixed heights of your header and footer.

All you need is this:

```
.header { height: 1.5em; } /* Fixed height, any unit */
.footer { height: 200px; } /* Fixed height, any unit */
.main { min-height: calc(100vh - 1.5em - 200px); } /* Calculated min-height */
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/jpunjng4/2/**

**Snippet:**

(*go full screen to see the effect*)

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
.header { height: 1.5em; background-color: #eef; border-bottom: 1px solid #999; }
.footer { height: 200px; background-color: #efe; border-top: 1px solid #999; }
.header, .footer { overflow: hidden; padding: 4px; }
.main { 
    min-height: calc(100vh - 1.5em - 200px); padding: 4px; 
    background-color: #eee; 
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    Header
</div>
<div class="main">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
</div>
```